# Which game does this die belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

My brother found a d6 die that had numbers 50, 100, 200, 500, 50 and 200 instead of normal 1-6. Which game is this die from?
[image]

Comment: Looks like there's a train on the 200. That might help your searches.

Comment: Showing the go to jail side would have made it much more obvious it's a monopoly game, since I've never seen another game using that symbol.

Comment: @Andrew go-to-jail side is on a different die: OP's brother found a die without it.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like this belongs to [Monopoly Express](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1420/monopoly-express):

[image]